# $(...).isotope is not a function using isotope JQuery plugins in angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, plugins

I'm using angular 4 to build an application.
I want to use isotope plugin to arrange and sort my elements.
when data in html is static, it work fine.
but when bind data from Server to elements don't work and This will make the error:$(...).isotope is not a function

> home.component.html

```
            <div class="isotope-items-wrap" #target>
          <div class="isotope-item height-2" data-filter="priceLowToHigh" *ngFor="let pItem of products;let idx=index;let last1 = last;">
            <img src="{{baseUrl}}{{pItem.image.path}}{{pItem.image.filename}}" *ngIf="pItem.image;else noImage" alt="Rug" />
            <ng-template #noImage>
              <div style="width: 280px;height: 482px;">no image
              </div>
            </ng-template>
            <h5>{{pItem.name}}</h5>
            <p>{{idx}}</p>
            <h5>{{pItem.price}}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
```

> home.component.ts

```
ngForCallback() {
    if (!this.ngForEnd) {
      await this.delay(1000);
      this.ngForEnd = true;
      var itemSelector = '.isotope-item';
      $('.isotope-items-wrap').isotope({
        itemSelector: itemSelector,
        transitionDuration: '0.5s',
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: itemSelector,
        },
      });
    } else {
      console.log('for was ended');
    }
  }
```

i import the isotope plugin js file in index.html and angular-cli.json

> index.html

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="./assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
```

> angular-cli.json

```
  "scripts": [
    "src/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js",
    "src/assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js",
    .
    .
  ],
```

Comment: You don't need to add it to both index.html and angular-cli.json, the CLI should add it into the document for you. Also, which one of those scripts contains the import plugin?

Comment: src="./assets/js/jquery.isotope.js"

Comment: Ah okay, it isn't showing in your question, that's all. If you check in the network tab of the developer tools, can you see it being loaded?

Comment: yes.this was loaded.

Comment: Any chance you can create a StackBlitz or similar that reproduces the issue?

Comment: this app has many dependent file.It's hard to load all the files.

Comment: I dont mean recreate the entire project, just create a [mcve]. When I try this in StackBlitz it seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdjhbx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Just checking, but is the isotope plugin file not within the `vendor` directory of assets as well?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c1mucb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Well in this case it's not working because there is no assets folder, and StackBlitz doesn't look at `angular-cli.json`. If you were to replace the URLs with CDN links for the StackBlitz, it would probably work

Comment: I had to remove `import * as $ from 'jquery';
window['$'] = $;
window['jquery'] = $;` from the `app.module` and use CDN link. After that it started working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rswk2i?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: thanks.it worked for me.